# Arduino loose serial-connection with our server

Tags: sockets, serial-port, arduino

We are trying to develop an webapplication that receive data from an arduino. We programmed arduino to send us back (on the web server) some JSON's every 5 seconds.
Everything works fine for about 1-2 minutes then suddenly we don't receive any data from arduino. Actually the TX keeps blinking but our console shows empty string.
Any ideeas? Thanks
PS. Baudrate is now set to 9600 if this tell you something :)

[Here is the link for code](http://pastebin.com/EBz5Cfgr)

Comment: Behavior like this is hard to debug without any code to look at; the phenomenon you describe can happen due to any number of reasons. We need more details to be able to help you.

Comment: Added my code in description. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: I'd try to first send the raw values from the array to the serial port instead of the JSON object, that way you'll know whether the problem lies with reading the sensor or with formatting the values into JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this github [issue page](https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson/issues/39) for the aJson library, it seems there is a memory leak in the `print(aJsonObject *)` function, which returns a buffer char array allocated with `malloc()`, so you're responsible for calling `free()` on it again. You are calling the function `print(aJsonObject *, aJsonStream *),` which then calls `printValue` and finally `print(aJsonObject *)`, however it does not keep references to the allocated array and consequently does not free it.

It seems then that making aJson send the data directly to the stream will only work if you modify all the functions that call `print(aJsonObject *)` to free the memory.

Alternatively, you can call `print(aJsonObject *)` yourself, send the contents of the char array out the serial port, and then free the memory. This is probably easier than to modify the many function calls in the library itself.

**Edit:** This seems to be the problem indeed, I have just tried your code on a Mega2560 and printed out the free memory after printing each JSON object (with the help of [this library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory)) , and got this:

```
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 7755
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 7644
<snip>
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 540
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 429
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 318
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 207
{"value1":500,"":1000} freeMemory = 153
 freeMemory = 153
 freeMemory = 153
 freeMemory = 153
```

However, there is one other thing you also have to do, namely calling `aJson.deleteItem()` on your json object, because that too contributes to the memory leak. Try changing the code in your loop to this:

```
aJsonObject *msg = createMessage();
char *json = aJson.print(msg);
Serial.print(json);
Serial.println();
free(json);
aJson.deleteItem(msg);
```

Now, the available memory stays the same after each loop iteration:

```
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 7884
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 7884
{"value1":500,"value2":1000,"value3":1500,"value4":2000} freeMemory = 7884
<snip>
```

**Edit 2:** Looks like using the stream works too, though you still have to call `aJson.deleteItem(msg)` after printing the data.

Comment: Yes that was it. Found the error when you posted first time. Didn't know that I should free memory. So i've searched and found aJson.deleteItem and saved me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you physically connecting the serial port? If you are using the usb port on a UNO or MEGA I have seen a situation where the DTR signal (which is connected to the atmega328 reset pin via a capacitor) can put the arduino into update mode.

Comment: Is this an Answer or a Comment?... please clarify your response.

Comment: Sorry, as the poster did not mention the hardware connection method (i.e serial via the direct pins or via the USB) i asked for more information and on the assumption of it being USB offered a possible reason for the failure. Apologies if i have offended, this is my first post.

Comment: Oh no, not at all. Just want to point you in the right direction. Sorry if it sound rude. This for example its a comment, like yours. And when you need to ask something to clarify the problem, you use comments. When you think that you have all the information to give an answer to OP problem, then you write an answer with the solution. This way its easy for new users with similar problem to identify the solution.